# Object initialization vs property assignment

Tags: c#

This morning, I had a discussion with a co-worker regarding the following two example of initializing the code.

Example 1:

```
var employee = new Employee();
employee.FirstName = GetFirstName();  // this may get values from db
```

Example 2:

```
var employee = new Employee() 
{
    FirstName = GetFirstName()
}
```

My co-worker's argument was that example 2 is more efficient and **if that object has any errors during initialization, it is automatically removed from heap**.  I am thinking that the compiled version of the code would look similar to example 1.

My question is that is my co-worker correct in his argument?  When should you use property assignment instead of object initialization?  Are there any best practices around this?  MS doesn't have anything ...

Comment: They're literally the same thing.  Check the IL.

Comment: Generated code is the same, while example 1 has better (more exact) line numbers if an exception occurs.

Comment: This is a compiler feature, not a run-time feature

Comment: @Caramiriel I forgot to mention in my orig post but that was my counter argument too.

Comment: Some general remarks. Calling database should be responsibility of other class, your constructor should receive just a value and initialize it. Although it is the same you should create and initialize the object fully within constructor, so from that point 2. example is better...

Comment: Just go to the C# spec. 12.7.11.3 Object initializers: "A member initializer that specifies an expression after the equals sign is processed in the same way as an assignment (§12.18.2) to the field or property."